# Python: where is the code for os.mkdir?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cpython

I've been looking through the code of the os module (just to be clear, I'm looking at the file /usr/lib/python2.7/os.py), and I've been trying to find the code for the mkdir function. From what I could tell, it comes from the 'posix' module, and its a built-in function, same as range or max:

```
>>> import posix
>>> posix.mkdir
<built-in function mkdir>
>>> max
<built-in function max>
```

I'm guessing the code for these is written in C somewhere, and the python interpreter knows where to find them. Could someone explain, or point me to some resources that do, how and where these built-in function are written and how they are integrated with the interpreter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

On POSIX platforms (and on Windows and OS/2) the `os` module imports from a C module, defined in [`posixmodule.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/posixmodule.c).

This module defines a [`posix_mkdir()` function](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/posixmodule.c#l2610) that wraps the [`mkdir()` C call](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mkdir) on POSIX platforms, `CreateDirectoryW` on Windows.

The module registers this function, together with others, in the module [`PyMethodDef posix_methods` structure](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/posixmodule.c#l8727). When the module is imported, Python calls the [`PyMODINIT_FUNC()` function](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/posixmodule.c#l9347), which uses that structure to create an approriate module object with the `posix_methods` structure and adds a series of constants (such as the [`open()` flag constants](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#open-flag-constants)) to the module.

See the [Extending Python with C or C++](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html) tutorial on how C extensions work.