# Can I step into Python library code?

Tags: python, debugging, libraries, system-calls, pdb

When I run my Python debugger, I can step into functions that I write. But if I try to step into a library function like `os.mkdir("folder")`, for example, it "steps over" it instead. Is there a way to step into builtin library functions to see what Python is doing under the hood?

Ideally there'd be a way to do this in PyPy so that you could keep drilling down into Python code.

Answer (score 9):

`pdb`, the Python Debugger, cannot step into C functions like `os.mkdir`, but `gdb` can.  Try this:

```
gdb --args python whatever.py ...
```

Then:

```
start
break posix_mkdir
continue
```

You should see it stop inside Python's implementation of os.mkdir, as detailed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16617835/4323

Answer (score 6):

`os.mkdir()` is implemented in C code and `pdb` cannot step into that function.

You are limited to debugging pure *Python* code only; it doesn't matter if that code is part of the standard library or not. You can step into the `shutil` module, or `os.path` just fine, for example.

`os.mkdir()` *has* to call into native code because it interacts with the OS; even PyPy has to defer to the underlying (host-Python) `os.mkdir()` call to handle that part, so you cannot step into it with `pdb` even in PyPy. In fact, just like in CPython, that part of the standard library is part of the RPython runtime and not seen as 'native Python code' by PyPy either, just like the built-in types are part of the runtime environment.

You could run the PyPy interpreter *untranslated* (so not statically compile the RPython code but have Python run the PyPy interpreter directly), but that'll only give you access to the RPython code paths, not the `os.mkdir()` C code.

Comment: @twasbrillig: functions that wrap OS functions still need to use natively compiled code, even in PyPy.

Comment: Thanks. Just curious though, what about a builtin, non-OS function like "string".index for example? Can that be stepped into using PyPy?

Comment: @twasbrillig: actually, you cannot step into code part of the rpython objects either; like the Python built-in types, in PyPy the built-in types are part of RPython and cannot be their code stepped into with the pdb debugger in PyPy.

Comment: Oh well. Thanks again for investigating it!