# How can I step into internal Python code in PyCharm?

Tags: python, internals

I want to follow what `import foo` does. When I try to step into it, it says `<frame not available>` in the debugger.

I have seen [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26198847/can-i-step-into-python-library-code) but it is asking for stepping into a Python C function.

Answer (score 0):

Use `importlib.import_module` instead.

Actually this works but then it doesn't step into `_bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)`. Maybe there is some filtering going on...

Answer (score 0):

Click on it once and then press `ctrl+Alt+B`. This will take you to the implementation of the library.

Alternatively, you can right-click on the library name and go to the `Go To` option. In the new sub-menu that appears click `implementation(s)`

Comment: It doesn't let me set breakpoints in the internals. I want to trace through, not just see the implementation.

Comment: oh, ok. I think i found what you are looking for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23071175/how-to-set-breakpoints-in-a-library-module-pdb)