# Benefit of using os.mkdir vs os.system("mkdir")

Tags: python, python-2.7

Simple question that I can't find an answer to:

Is there a benefit of using `os.mkdir("somedir")` over `os.system("mkdir somedir")` or `subprocess.call()`, beyond code portability?

Answers should apply to Python 2.7.

Edit: the point was raised that a hard-coded directory versus a variable (possibly containing user-defined data) introduces the question of security. My original question was intended to be from a system approach (i.e. what's going on under the hood) but security concerns are a valid issue and should be included when considering a complete answer, as well as directory names containing spaces

Comment: Well, `somedir` is a variable in the first case.

Comment: One difference is `os.mkdir` will raise an exception if something goes wrong, while you'll have to check the output and/or return value otherwise.

Comment: The return value isn't good enough. Quoting from the manual: "DIAGNOSTICS
     The mkdir utility exits 0 on success, and >0 if an error occurs." -- it doesn't tell you *what kind* of error.

Comment: somedir being a variable doesn't change the question but I've edited it anyway

Comment: @TheOx, per your edits, you mean to ask this only with a hardcoded variable name? It *does* change the question, because names you don't control have more issues (security ones, for instance). If you want a maximally general answer, you should ask with the name being a variable in all cases.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The focus of the question was meant to be from a system standpoint (i.e. the underlying mechanisms behind the various options) but security issues for user-defined input are most definitely valid and I should have more clearly defined the question.

Comment: @TheOx It does make a difference that it's a variable. The value would need quoting and escaping correctly if you passed it to `os.system`. It's more difficult to use correctly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Correctness

Think about what happens if your directory name contains spaces:

```
mkdir hello world
```

...creates *two* directories, `hello` and `world`. And if you just blindly substitute in quotes, that won't work if your filename contains that quoting type:

```
'mkdir "' + somedir + '"'
```

...does very little good when `somedir` contains `hello "cruel world".d`.

---

### Security

In the case of:

```
os.system('mkdir somedir')
```

...consider what happens if the variable you're substituting for `somedir` is called `./$(rm -rf /)/hello`.

Also, calling `os.system()` (or `subprocess.call()` with `shell=True`) invokes a shell, which means that you can be open to bugs such as ShellShock; if your `/bin/sh` were provided by a ShellShock-vulnerable bash, and your code provided any mechanism for arbitrary environment variables to be present (as is the case with HTTP headers via CGI), this would provide an opportunity for code injection.

---

### Performance

```
os.system('mkdir somedir')
```

...starts a shell:

```
/bin/sh -c 'mkdir somedir'
```

...which then needs to be linked and loaded; needs to parse its arguments; and needs to invoke the *external command* `mkdir` (meaning *another* link and load cycle).

---

A significant improvement is the following:

```
subprocess.call(['mkdir', '--', somedir], shell=False)
```

...which only invokes the external `mkdir` command, with no shell; however, as it involves a fork()/exec() cycle, this is still a significant performance penalty over the C-library `mkdir()` call.

In the case of `os.mkdir(somedir)`, the Python interpreter directly invokes the appropriate syscall -- no external commands at all.

---

### Error Handling

If you call `os.mkdir('somedir')` and it fails, you get an `IOError` with the appropriate `errno` thrown, and can trivially determine the type of the error.

If the `mkdir` external command fails, you get a failed exit status, but no handle on the actual underlying problem without parsing its stderr (which is written for humans, not machine readability, and which will vary in contents depending on the system's current locale).

Comment: Also, if the directory path has spaces in it, the path needs quoting. And possibly escaping too.

Comment: @PeterWood, quite right. Added "correctness" as its own section.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This is a great answer. I feel I've learned a lot about how to answer questions well.

Comment: What about cross platform compatibility? `os.system("mkdir...` might not be the right command to create a folder on the underlying OS, and the filesystem/shell quoting rules might be different. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16617835/478656 has Martijn Peters' explanation of os.mkdir on Linux / Windows and links to the CPython source code.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, indeed. The OP acknowledged portability as an issue in their question, however, so that one was already known / on the table. (Thank you for the link -- that's a useful addition!)